# Regular expression for apikey pattern

Tags: regex, bash, sed, command-line, grep

I am not expert in regular expression and tried various approach but did not work. I am trying to find occurrence of particular pattern of apikey in logfile.

```
[SOME TEXT]http_apikey=""abc123pq-ab33-ffef-979f-d78a3d27g84f[SOME TEXT]
[SOME TEXT]http_apikey=""abc1-23-pq-ab33-ffef-979f-d78a3d27g84f[SOME TEXT]
[SOME TEXT]http_apikey=""abc1-23-pq-ab33-ffef-979f-d78a3d27g84f[SOME TEXT]
[SOME TEXT]http_apikey=""abc1-23pq-ab33-ffef-979f-d78a-3d27-g84f[SOME TEXT]
[SOME TEXT]http_apikey=""abc123pq-ab33ffef-979fd78a-3d27g84f[SOME TEXT]
[SOME TEXT]http_apikey=""a7wLi3gPFon7VeBUdN7ZE8lQjofa22ie[SOME TEXT]
```

I want to find all the apikey which has one or more '-' character in it; I want to single regular expression through grep ; I tried first search "http_apikey.{0,40}" then pipe it and again search for '-' in string but it's very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the pattern a bit more specific using a character class `[a-z0-9]` instead of using a `.`

Using grep, you match at least 2 times the hyphen between the character class:

```
grep 'apikey=""[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]*-[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]*-[a-z0-9]' file
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQrshZ/1)

If you can use egrep, you can repeat the group 2 or more times `{2,}` using a quantifier :

```
egrep 'apikey=""[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+){2,}' file
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pRzjyh/1)

Answer (score 1):

Single grep would be:

`cat file|grep 'apikey=\"\".*[-].*'`

or to match only the key itself:

`cat file|grep -oP '(?<=apikey="").*[-].*(?=\[.+)'`

Is this what you need?